# iosで、アプリ独自フォーマットのファイルをメールでやり取りする

Tags: ios

iosアプリで作成したデータ（独自フォーマット）を他のユーザにも取り込んで使ってもらえるようにしたいと考えており、簡便な方法として、アプリからメールの添付ファイルとしてデータを送り、受け手側ではその添付ファイルを当該アプリで開くことで読み込むようにしたいと考えております。

その際に、受け手側で添付ファイルアイコンにタッチしたときに出るメニューに、自分のアプリを表示させる方法がわかりません。

具体例として、neu.Notes+というアプリで作ったファイル（拡張子.neunote）を添付して送ったメールを、受け手側がiosの標準メールアプリで開き、添付ファイルをタッチすると、メニューに「メッセージ」「メールで送信」等に混ざって「Notes+で開く」というアイコンが表示され、これにタッチするとneu.Notes+が立ち上がって当該ファイルを開くことができます。

同様にTopNotesというアプリで作ったファイル（拡張子.notebook）の場合、このときには受け手側で添付ファイルをタッチすると「TopNotesで開く」というアイコンが表示されますが、「Notes+で開く」というアイコンは表示されません。

これらの例で、標準メールアプリが添付ファイルのタッチ時の振る舞いをファイルによって変えているので、何らかの方法でiosにファイルの種類と対応アプリを教えているのだと思うのですが、その方法をご教示いただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: 「iOS 拡張子 関連付け」あたりで検索すると、分かりやすく書かれた記事がいくつか見つかると思います。回答の形にまとめようとすると全文丸パクリになりそうなので、あきらめました。注意点としては、拡張子がどのアプリと結びついているのかを設定しているのであって、メールアプリの振る舞いを変えているわけではないので、Safariなんかからのダウンロードでも関連付けされたアプリを選べるようになります。

Comment: なかなか素早くポイントを掴まれたようですね。無事にご自身の問題を解決されましたら、ご自分の質問にご自身で回答をつける(それに解決マークをつける)こともできるはずですので、ぜひお時間を取ってみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございました。質問内容だけでなく、スタック・オーバーフローの使い方も勉強になりました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

質問者による回答です。

コメントをいただき「iOS 拡張子 関連付け」で検索すると、役立ちそうな情報が見つかりました。

iOSに対してやることは以下の2つです。

1. 独自の拡張子を定義
   Info.plistに
   <key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
   で始まる記述を追加。
2. その拡張子とアプリの関連付け
   Info.plistに
   <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
   で始まる記述を追加。

公式ドキュメントでは、[「iOSドキュメントインタラクションプログラミングトピックス」](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS.pdf)
というのも役立ちそうです。